# How to run/test code in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio

How can I run/text code in visual studio code? What I mean if, for example, I have the following code:

```py
i = 0
while i < 5:
    print("test")
    i += 1
```

then I would like to get the output:

```
test
test
test
test
test
```

I used jupyter notebook before and this was possible but I can't do this in vscode and they're forcing me to use vscode.

Answer (score 0):

Press F5. You can set a breakpoint by clicking to the left of you line number. See [VS Code Debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) for more information. You'll need to install the ms-python extension to get python support (see the above link). Naturally, you can simply invoke your compiler in the terminal as well (Control+` to bring up terminal).